# ASP.NET Gridview delete row only on confirmation

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, confirm

I have a `gridview` with the `onRowDeleting` method implemented. I would like to prompt the user with a pop up message to confirm whether they wish to delete this item or not.
If the user clicks "OK", "Confirm" or something similar then I would like the `onRowsDeleting` to be process and the record deleted. But if the user pressed "No" then I would like the method to be cancelled and the record not deleted.

How can this be done?

Here is my `gridview` and `onRowDeleting` method in the code behind.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvShowQuestionnaires" HeaderStyle-CssClass="table_header" CssClass="view" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#f3f4f8" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames='QuestionnaireID' OnRowDeleting="gvShowQuestionnaires_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="gvShowQuestionnaires_RowEdit" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvShowQuestionnaires_SelectedIndexChanged" FooterStyle-CssClass="view_table_footer" > 
    <Columns>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="QuestionnaireID" HeaderText="ID" HeaderStyle-Width="80px" ItemStyle-CssClass="bo"></asp:BoundField>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="QuestionnaireName" HeaderText="Questionnaire Name" />                     
         <asp:ButtonField CommandName="select" ButtonType="Link" Text="view results" />
         <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Options" CausesValidation="true" ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="true" EditText="Edit">
         </asp:CommandField>
     </Columns> 
</asp:GridView>

protected void gvShowQuestionnaires_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{       
    int questionnaireID = (int)gvShowQuestionnaires.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex)].Value; 
    GetData.DeleteQuestionnaire(questionnaireID);
    gvShowQuestionnaires.DataSource = DT;
    gvShowQuestionnaires.DataBind();
    lblActivity.Visible = true;
    lblActivity.Text = "Your questionnaire has been deleted";
}
```

Comment: This might help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb428868.aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should do that on clientside with javascript.

Therefore you can handle GridView's [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event to add this to the Delete-Button's `OnClientClick`:

```
protected void gvShowQuestionnaires_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // reference the Delete LinkButton
        LinkButton db = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[3].Controls[0];

        db.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you certain you want to delete this questionnaire?');";
    }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb428868.aspx

This js-function will return whether the user clicked `ok` or `cancel`. If a js-eventhandler returns `false`, the page will not postback to the  server.

Answer (score 5):

The "return confirm(..") Javascript is on the right track.

The problem is that ASP.NET will append js to call __doPostBack

so you'll get something like this in your HTML for the delete button:

```
OnClickClient="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');";javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$Main$PlansGrid&#39;,&#39;Delete$101&#39;)"
```

What happens is:
1) User clicks Delete button.
2) Confirm dialog displayed.
3) User clicks on OK button.
4) Confirm returns True.
5) return at beginning of statement executes and __doPostBack is not called.

The solution is to return only if confirm returns false:

```
OnClientClick="if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Plan?')) return;"
```

If user clicks OK confirm returns True and then __doPostBack executes.

Comment: This is good information. However, merely returning at times goes straight into the handler. Adjusting the function to return either true or false would fix it up; OnClientClick="if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Plan?')) {return false;} else{return true;}"

Comment: great solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simply call a JavaScript function returning a boolean by "return" caller so if returns false this link button will not work.

ASPX

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClientClick="return DeleteItem();" locationID='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem,"Id").ToString() %>' ID="linkDelete" OnClick="linkDelete_Click" title='<%# "Delete " + DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem,"City").ToString() %>' Style="float: left;"><img src="Asset/img/icon/bin.gif" alt="" hspace="3" /></asp:LinkButton>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function DeleteItem() {
        if (confirm("Delete this Location?")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Server Side

```
protected void linkDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       int locationID =0;
       int.TryParse(((LinkButton)sender).Attributes["locationID"].ToString(),out locationID);

       if (locationID > 0)
       {
           Location loc = Location.GetById(locationID);
           CurrentDataContext.CurrentContext.DeleteObject(loc);
           CurrentDataContext.CurrentContext.SaveChanges();
           bindGv();
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            // loop all data rows
            foreach (DataControlFieldCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
            {
                // check all cells in one row
                foreach (Control control in cell.Controls)
                {
                    // Must use LinkButton here instead of ImageButton
                    // if you are having Links (not images) as the command button.
                    LinkButton button = control as LinkButton;
                    if (button != null && button.CommandName == "Delete")
                        // Add delete confirmation
                        button.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you sure " +
                               "you want to delete this record?');";
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        string id = e.Row.Cells[2].Text;
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            LinkButton db = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[6].Controls[0];
            db.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you want to delete this Work Description : " + id + "?');";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get by command button type

```
protected void gvShowQuestionnaires_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // handle the Command Column Index
        var commandColumnIndex = GvOperators.Columns
              .OfType<DataControlField>()
              .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Column = x })
              .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Column is CommandField)
              .Index;

        var commandButtons = e.Row.Cells[commandColumnIndex].Controls.OfType<LinkButton>();

        // reference the Delete LinkButton
        var db = commandButtons.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CommandName == "Delete");
        if(db!=null)       
          db.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you certain you want to delete this questionnaire?');";
    }
}
```